# rspec expected || got nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am new to testing in rails. I am trying to test the update action for my systems controller in my application using rspec.

Here is the code for the test I am running:

```
describe 'Put update' do 
    before (:each) do
        @system = FactoryGirl.create(:system, name:"WAM", responsible_personnel: "Jeff", criticality: 1, status: "Available")
    end 

    context "valid attributes" do 
        it "located the requested @system" do
            put :update, id: @system, system: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:system)
            assigns(:contact).should eq(@system)
        end
    end
end
```

My factory code:

```
 # spec/factories/systems.rb 
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do  
 factory :system do |f|
    f.name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    f.responsible_personnel { Faker::Name.name}
    f.criticality {Faker::Number.between(1,5)}
    f.status "Available" || "Unavailable"
 end

 factory :invalid_system, parent: :system do |f|
    f.name nil
 end
end
```

When I run the test i get this error:

```
 expected: #<System id: 285, name: "WAM", responsible_personnel: "Jeff", created_at: "2016-02-25 18:34:43", updated_at: "2016-02-25 18:34:43", criticality: 1, status: 0>
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

Here is my systems controller update action

```
def update
  if @system.update(system_params)
    flash[:success] = "System successfully updated."
    redirect_to edit_system_path
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like something in your controller code failed to run, or didn't assign that variable like you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spec is expecting there to be a variable called `@contact` created in your controller. I'm guessing that's a typo, and your `assigns` statement should be:

```
assigns(:system).should eq(@system)
```

Comment: I must have overlooked that when i was going through my test. This solved my error.